# Push-animate a floated div by animated div to left

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to CSS animate a div's left property resulting in a div that's floated next to it moving the same incremental amount automatically?

I've produced some jsfiddle code that demonstrates my question not working the way I would like it to. Click on the red square to see it animate, albeit over the top of the blue square.

I would like #block1 to be able to in effect push #block2 by animating the CSS property 'left' of block1.

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.red {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #F00;
}

.blue {
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #00F;
}

.animateMenu {
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 0.5s forwards;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 100px;}
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="block1" class="red"></div>
<div id="block2" class="blue"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#block1").on( { "mousedown" : onInteraction } );

function onInteraction(e) {
    $("#block1").removeClass("animateMenu").addClass("animateMenu");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6edgsanb/

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of animating `left`, animate `margin-left`. Here's a modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/6edgsanb/1/).